# How to reveal the contents of Android's /data/data?

Tags: android, android-file

The directory `/data` is empty when I look through DDMS's File Explorer.

It is also empty after I run `adb pull /data /myLocalCopy`.

Yet `context.getFileStreamPath("myFile.txt")` says that `myFile.txt` will land in `/data/data/com.corp.appName/files/myFile.txt` after calling `context.openFileOutput("myFile.txt", ..)`.

How do I run an `ls -al /data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directory is not readable for normal processes. You must be `root` (or `system`) to see the contents. So either try with a rooted phone or with the emulator.

Looking at the permission settings:

```
drwxrwx--x system   system            2012-07-24 21:47 data
```

you see that normal users can not list the directory contents (would require `r` permission) but can access files below (the `x` permission is there). Therefore it is not a contradiction that files can be stored and accessed below `/data`

In particular, the system creates a directory `/data/data/com.corp.appName` which is owned by the application `com.corp.appName` so that this application has full access rights in this subtree.

Comment: That makes sense. Does that mean that there is no way to endow DDMS with the same privileges as my application while developing? Does just peeking at what my application has written require reading from the application itself, and not from any Eclipse/ADT utility?

Comment: When your application is built in debug mode, you can work from the command line: `adb shell` and then `run-as com.corp.appName` gives you access to the files of the app.

Comment: One more (sequel :) question... After `adb shell` and `run-as ...`, is there a way to copy a file from the device to the desktop machine?

Comment: Yes, `cat the-file-to-copy > /sdcard/some-temp-location` and then copy it from the temp location.